# Need a Intuitive thinking for the proof of Mean value theorem for scalar field

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Ok so the proof is laid out on my book but I'm genuinely struggling to have a geometrical/Intuitive thinking to this particular proof. I badly need help with it.

So here is the statement of the proof (PLEASE NOTE THAT $D_u$ in this case implies directional derivative in the direction of the unit vector $u$):

Let $f: S\to \mathbb R$ be a scalar field. Let $a\in S$ and where $S\subseteq \mathbb R^n$

So let $u$ be a unit vector and $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a + ut \in S$ for all $0\leq t \leq 1.$ Suppose $D_uf(a)$ exists for all $a + ut$ where $0 \leq t \leq 1$ then there exist a $\theta$ such that $0<\theta<1$ and

$$f(a+u)-f(a) = D_uf(z), \text{where }z= a + u\theta$$

Now I'm not gonna write the proof that is written in my book because I fairly understood the steps well. I don't understand where this $z= a + u\theta$ came or what does it even imply or how it looks geometrically.

Comment: Anyone who is more familiar with the formatting in this website is more than welcome to edit my post to make it look more presentable and edit the notation for better understanding. Thank you!

Comment: I've modified your first line of equations. Look up LaTex math symbols if you need help with the rest

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: $a+u\theta$ is just a point on the segment joining $a$ and $a+u$ (if we identify the vectors with heir endpoints.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: S\to \mathbb R$ be a scalar field. Let $a\in S$ and where $S\subseteq \mathbb R^n$.

> So let $u$ be a unit vector and $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a + ut \in S$ for all $0\leq t \leq 1.$

$S$ is some region in $\mathbb{R^n}$; $a$ is within $S$ such that all points up to $1$ unit away in the $\arg(u)$ direction are also in $S$. We define $A$ as the segment leading from $a$ to $a+ut$; i.e. $A:=\{ a+ut | t\in[0,1]\}$.

> Suppose $D_uf(a)$ exists for all $a + ut$ where $0 \leq t \leq 1$ then there exists a $\theta$ such that $0<\theta<1$ and
>
> $$f(a+u)-f(a) = D_uf(z), \text{where }z= a + u\theta$$

$z$ lies in $A$, as $z=a+u\theta$ for some $\theta\in[0,1]$. So this is saying: for some point on this line $A$, there exists a point $z\in A$ such that the derivative of $S$ at $z$ is equal to the difference of the values of $f$ at the endpoints of $A$; the "mean value" of $f$ on $A$.

This is notated a little confusingly; I'm not a fan of using $t$ and $\theta$ to parametrize the same thing. Also $a,u,z$ seem to have no clear pattern.

Comment: God bless you!!! everything is completely clear now! thank you so much seriously!